# Convert numbered references into author year reference

Tags: citing, elsarticle

I am having a Query related to conversion of my numbered references into simple author year citation.
I tried using;
Bibliographystyle(authoryear) but it didn't worked.

Comment: you tagged this as biblatex, are you using biblatex or bibtex? please show exactly the syntax you used, where did you put `Bibliographystyle(authoryear) ` ? and exactly what error you got. Preferably show a small complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The instruction `\bibliographystyle(authoryear)` seems quite odd. The usual way to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs under BibTeX is to (a) load a suitable citation management package (e.g., `natbib` or `apacite`) and (b) employ a bibliography style file that can generate the required citation style. (Some, but certainly not all, bibliography style files can generate both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs.) In short, please do tell us how you've been creating numeric-style citation call-outs so far.